# How to run an application in User B from user A

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc, tomcat, system-administration

I have a REST endpoint (developed with spring mvc) on windows server that has more than one user, tomcat instance is running under admin user, from that user I need to start an application in another user under the same server, can I do that using CMD command somehow?

so, Admin will receive REST request, and based on the parameters given, REST endpoint will run an application ( notepad as example ) in another user under the same server.

I hope that my question is clear.

what I was thinking to do is, to start tomcat instance under all the users and deploy web services that can handle this request, but it will be easier for me to use CMD command instead, but I have no idea about administrations.

in short, from user A, I need to start notepad.exe in user B.

Comment: Why are your web services sensitive to the local system user running the server process? All services should probably run with as low privileges as you can get away with. Certainly not as "admin". This question sounds more like "if I compromise a service running as 'admin', how can I attack other local users on the server?"

Comment: because I will receive the request on one user( in fact I don't care if it is admin or not ), what I really need is to receive the request on user A, and start an application in the other users based on the request parameters.

Comment: Starting an application on the server as a specific user is a Red Flag to me. That's either an intentional security issue being introduced or a lapse in architectural judgement. *Why* does some program need to be run under different privileges than that of the server (Tomcat) process? Your `notepad.exe` example is obviously contrived because running `notepad.exe` – or really any GUI-based application – from a JVM would be entirely useless. So what is your *actual* use-case?

Comment: Why I feel like you are attacking :D,, I am just asking, if it is not possible, you can say that, I have no idea about administration and security, so for me I have to find the best way to do my work

Comment: What you are asking about *is* possible, but dangerous and usually the wrong approach. If you describe what your actual goal is (rather than the technique you have chosen to accomplish that goal), you may get better feedback.

Comment: my goal is to start testing automation execution in a server, in this server I have 4 users, I need to run automation tool in all or some of the users. for that I assumed that I have two approaches, to **start tomcat server** in each user with different ports, so my REST api will handle this request in this user, Or to **receive the request in one user** and send a command somehow from this user to the other users to start automation tool and start execution. @ChristopherSchultz